# Keep array order in select HTML

Tags: php, cakephp

My question is.
I have an array, in which the elements positioned in this way:

[2] => 'Value of 2'
[3] => 'Value of 3'
[1] => 'Value of 1'

And I want to appear that way on  .
But when sending data to the PHP / HTML, they are ordered.

[1] => 'Value of 1'
[2] => 'Value of 2'
[3] => 'Value of 3'

Note: The key must be kept, I can not for example do the following:
[1] => 'Value of 2'
[2] => 'Value of 3'
[3] => 'Value of 1'

Should I keep the keys in place.

(I'm using Google Translate)

**EDIT:**

I'm using this field in CakePHP:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('item_id', array('label' => 'Item', 'class' => 'span3', 'empty' => 'Escolha um item', 'data-depend-on' => '#ActionEstoqueId', 'data-source' => $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'itens', 'action' => 'index', 'ext' => 'json'), true))) ?>
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, I'm from Brazil too =P

Comment: Is 'Value of key 2' a string with these 14 characters, or is it supposed to be a reference?
The order is important, but are the key values important?

Comment: How are you sending this array and where are you sending this array from?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @EricG the key its important because, this is "ID" of register.

Comment: @Palladium I'll send with json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how is this for you? (Scroll below for the update, as this original answer was not helpful).

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        "2" => "Value of 2",
        "3" => "Value of 3",
        "1" => "Value of 1",
    );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $array );
    echo "</pre>";

    // Or

    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.'=>'.$value.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

Update:

```
$array = array(
    array( "2", "Value of 2" );
    array( "3", "Value of 3" );
    array( "1", "Value of 1" );
)
```

I really don't know how this is converted as a response object, you should let me know I guess.

Comment: Doing it this way works, but the array is mounted on PHP, and returned to the AJAX-VIEW (json). When sending, it is reorganized, I do not know why.

Comment: Are you saying the json version is reordered, alphabetically..? Perhaps you should change keys to "_1", "_2" because the JSON parser might consider the "2" as a number in stead of strings. How is that?

Comment: @EriG No. Json reordered numeric. [1], [2], [3]. And the correctly is: [2] [3] [1]

Comment: @EriG You're correctly. jSON reordered alpabetically. Now is the question: why? And, how I fix that?

Comment: Tomorrow I'll look further. You will need to save an unordered array with keys and values, non asociative. Should be quite easy.

Comment: Yes of course. This way works correctly, the problem is how do I get the index of the selected value after? Since the 'name' is not unique (not a slug). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I guess you will need a mapper or so (Unless you are saying that you are having duplicate keys). Apologies for not responding as quick stated.

Comment: Sorry, you could convert your response object or use a helper method like myArray.getFromKey('2')

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to instead do this?

```
$arr = array(
    array(2 => 'Value of 2'),
    array(3 => 'Value of 3'),
    array(1 => 'Value of 1')
);
```

Comment: Works only in PHP file. If I try to mount the file within the array, and populate the select, it works perfectly. But as the array is populated in the Controller, and returned to Ajax-View (json), it reorganizes. I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use php function :

```
ksort($array);
```

You can see  function working on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Comment: But this function only sorts the array by index right? And what I want is just to keep the ordernação I created, not the correct ordering.